# auto suggested text intermittently changes what I have typed

Tags: keyboard, firefox, mouse, auto-completion

This is difficult to describe because it is intermittent. But sometimes when I type in Firefox on Ubuntu, the suggested text in the drop-down box will overwrite what I have typed. This doesn't seem to be related to any particular web-site. It happens both on the address bar and in a search box. Both seem to have suggested text pop up in a drop down box. This is very useful, but its strange (and very annoying) that the suggestion will sometimes overtype what I have already typed manually.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that this is actually two problems. Most web-pages seem to have their own auto completion built in to their search boxes. If I unintentionally hover the mouse over the drop-down one of these is selected. Although what I have typed is still in the search bar, when I press enter it changes to what was selected with the mouse. So it seems the mouse is the problem for me.
The solution is to retype the text and make sure that the mouse is not near the selection. So I have to keep track of what my mouse pointer is doing while typing.